# How to calculate coordinates of ball when collided with a wall?

Tags: javascript, linear-algebra, game-physics

I'm developing a game like bubble shooter and need to implement bounce of ball off the vertical wall. I have the following inputs:

1. Starting position of bubble: `{left: 382, right: 378}`
2. Firing angle in radians: `1.34`
3. Game board sizes: `{width: 760, height: 620}`.
4. Sizes of the bubble are `{width: 44px, height: 44px}`

I have two walls to the left side of the bubble and to the right side of the bubble.

How could I calculate bubble's center point coordinates to stop it on collided left of right wall?

[image]

Comment: three important items are missing from your input data. What is the size and shape of the bubble? What direction is angle 0? Is angle the clockwise or counter clockwise from 0?

Comment: I've updated the post with sizes. I don't thought eat about direction if angle is 0, I think I need to set min angle possible.

Comment: angle 1.34 radians means nothing if you don't know where angle 0 is, or which direction (clockwise or counter clockwise) the angle is measured in

Comment: I've added the image that I hope answers your question

Comment: So, firing angle is 1.34

Comment: @Jaromanda X angle is counter clock wise

Answer (score 0):

If the dimensions for the bubble are 44x44, I assume it means that the bounding box is that size (because you don't measure circles with width and height).

If that's the case, than you have something like

[image: box]

That means that the diameter of the circle is 44px, which means the radius of the circle is 22px. The distance from the wall to the center of the circle, assuming the wall is tangent to the circle, would be `1r` or 22px.

If you're counting from the top left of the bounding box, you want to add 22px to both the x and the y coordinate, and that would give you the coordinates of the center.

Comment: Ok, but how could I calculate `x, y` where should I stop bubble http://buildanhtml5game.com/?page_id=20 ?

Comment: I don't know. It depends on what's your coordinate system. If the position of a bubble is determined by where is its top left corner, you want to stop the bubble 0px from the left wall, and 44px from the right wall. If it's from the center, you want to stop 22px from either way.

Comment: My problem is I don't understand how to calculate `top` coordinate. Please look the game http://buildanhtml5game.com/?page_id=20. At now the bubble does't stop on wall. I need to calculate `top` and `left` coordinates to stop it in right place on the wall

Comment: @Erik This is strictly a math problem, not a programming one. If you don't understand the math behind it, perhaps you should ask on [math.se] or a similar forum.

Comment: I've asked about it http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1357888/how-to-calculate-coordinates-of-ball-when-collided-with-a-wall and admins are closed it :(